# How to generate unique string which in not into specific array?

Tags: php

I want to generate unique string.

My code is:

```
function string(){
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $str= '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $str.= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

above code through I'm Generate unique string but that string must not in below array

```
$array = array('adc','Fs5','sf9','9Sf', ..........);
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check if string is in array with `in_array` function.

Comment: Erm... just check it? For example using `do..while`?

Comment: You dont have any option other than brute forcing in a while loop.

Comment: Btw, wouldn't `hash('sha256',time())` been easier?

Comment: I think the easiest way could be `md5(time())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array('adc','Fs5','sf9','9Sf', ..........);

function string() {
    global $array;

    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

    do {
      $str= '';
      for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $str.= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
      } 
    } while (in_array($str, $array));

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: you should add `global $array;`